# Running a timer on asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, timer, counter, global-asax

I have project and I have `Global.asax`file.
I have in it few methods like `Application_Start` which sets a counter for sessions, `Session_Start` which increments sessions, `Session_End` which decrements session and `Application_End` which prints the session's counter.

I wanted to print a counter every hour so that my code:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application["LiveSessionsCount"] = 0;

        Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1 * 60 * 1000); //one hour in milliseconds
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(LogCounterForSessions);
    }

    private void LogCounterForSessions(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.ForceWrite("LogCounterForSessions: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss") + " - session's count: " + (int)Application["LiveSessionsCount"]);
    }
```

My problem is that there was no log (so I decreased the time to a mintues, but no log written). When application ends the log works.

Any suggestions why doesn't it work?

Comment: Are you starting the timer ?

Comment: You should take a look at [Quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net).

Comment: @Boney Poor am I... Didn't enable it :( Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I needed to start it by writing

```
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```